# How to fix when JPanel.repaint() doesn't call paintComponent //nothing I found that work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm going to create a JPanel Howto, which is rendering 6 images in order and then add the back button to go back to title.

I'm trying check if it call paintComponent method in class howto or not. And it doesn't so the value i is still 0 and end up stuck in loop

Here's my Howto class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Audio.HitSound;
import Graphic.DrawingUtility;

public class Howto extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private JButton back;
    private static int i;
    public Howto(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setLayout(null);
    repaint();
    HitSound h = new HitSound();
    i=0;
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while(i<6)
            {
                GameManager.frame.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if(GameManager.thread.isAlive()){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(DrawingUtility.getHowto(i), 0, 0, 800, 600,null);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

and this what in my GameManager class

```
public static void startThread() {
        thread = new Thread(howto);
        thread.start();
    }

public static void runHowto() {
    howto = new Howto();
    howto.setVisible(true);
    frame.switchScene(howto);
    howto.repaint();
    startThread();
    while (thread.isAlive()) {
        //frame.repaint();
    }
    if (!thread.isAlive()) {
        JButton back = new JButton();
        back.setBorderPainted(false);
        back.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        back.setFocusPainted(false);
        back.setOpaque(false);
        back.setBounds(640, 446, 132, 132);
        back.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HitSound h = new HitSound();
                h.play(3);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GameManager.goToTitle();
            }
        });
    }
```

but when I call runHowto(); it's still looping and i == 0 and not increase i 
So I think it's may have problem with paintComponent and repaint method

So please help me fixing it Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think it's an issue with your threads, but since I don't have a runnable example, I can't say for sure. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Also, you seem to be making a large reliance on `static` to allow you classes to talk with each other, this is a really bad idea

Comment: Thanks you for your advice :)
It's my very first time here so sorry about my confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

The `while (thread.isAlive())` loop blocks the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

You need to return to the event dispatch loop from `runHowto`. Have your `Howto` task to post back to the EDT with `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` to construct your back button and presumably add it to a panel.

Comment: What proof do you have that `runHowto` is been executed from within the EDT?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It should be. It's using Swing. (`repaint` is one of those methods that is exceptionally allowed.)

Comment: But `runHowto` could be getting called in a different thread, given the use of `startThread`, but no where in the code snippet, is it called, so at best, it's an assumption

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's a pretty good assumption given that the method is doing things that should only be done on the EDT and it would cause the problem found.

Comment: You're still assume that the OP understands that Swing is not thread safe (which if they did, they would also know not to block the EDT), given some of the other things that the OP is doing, I would discount that :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP doesn't need to understand that. Unless called through `main` (which seems unlikely to me), OP would have to do something special to get onto a different thread, but OP is having trouble apparently doing that for the first time in this question. And EDT blocking is a very common mistake that causes the observed behaviour.

Comment: Given that most people (still) don't use `EventQueue.invokeLater` to start their UI's I'd say it's more likely they might have executed the code from the main thread.  Given the fact that they are also starting thread's in the example code, it's a good bet. Not adding the component to the UI would also generate the observed behavior, as well thread read/write issues. There's simply not enough code to provide an adequate diagnostics to the OP's problem and too many possible causes, which leads to guess work and assumptions. IMHO the OP should encouraged to provide a working example

Comment: @MadProgrammer It doesn't matter how the GUI is kicked off. I'd assume an animation is kicked off by some input event. Indeed this is implied by the first line of the question. But given skill and experience, there's enough information here for us to have a good probability of finding the cause. / There's no need to cause more work isolating the problem. However, you could create a long list of things that could be improved by about this code, but aren't relevant.